# Prisma Mongo Scalar Limit

Tags: javascript, mongodb, prisma

can I query limit scalar list query?
Example model:

```
model Test {
  id                  String           @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  results             TestResults[]
}
type TestResults{
  batch   Int
}
```

Can I do a query that only get 1 results from this scalar list?
Thanks in advance for helping

I expect the response will be one data from this array and not all

Comment: Do you mean that while fetching Test, you only want one record of TestResults?

Comment: Yes, i want to query many result of Test and only get one record of TestResults

Comment: You can limit the number of records for Test model, but currently it's not natively possible to limit number of TestResults type. You would need to get the TestResults and then manually get one TestResult before sending it to client